# Laravel 4.2 Redirector Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

I've been using Laravel 4.2 for quite a while ( still learning ) but I can't seem to use **any of the Redirect::** functions

This is the error

> Class 'Illuminate\Routing\Redirector' not found

This is my code.

```
class RegisterController extends BaseController {

    public function confirm()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Registration::$rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find anything about this issue on Google.
Anyone experienced this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run `composer update`?

Comment: Wow that was it! How can it come without Redirect class? This normally never happens. If you make it an answer i'll accept it

Comment: It is weird indeed. Maybe it just failed to download it or something like that. How did you do the install?

Comment: I used composer create-project laravel/laravel installdir --prefer-dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With missing classes from a framework/package it always helps to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Or even `update` (which will call `dump-autoload` too)

```
composer update
```